# How to prevent PostgreSQL to make uncontrolled checkpoints?

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to disable PostgreSQL to auto checkpoint.

I just want to fsync wal files on disk without saving changes made in shared_buffer.

I set `checkpoint_segments` and `checkpoint_timeout` to big values, but still it makes additional checkpoints.

I don't want to checkpoint not even he needs to swap pages or is out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

There are other causes for checkpoints:

- Recovery has finished (could happen after a server crash).
- Start of an online backup.
- Database shutdown.
- Before and after `CREATE DATABASE`.
- After `DROP DATABASE`.
- Before and after `ALTER DATABASE SET TABLESPACE` (you probably don't do that every day).
- During `DROP TABLESPACE` (ditto).
- And, of course, an explicit `CHECKPOINT` command.

I hope I haven't forgotten anything – could one of these cause the checkpoints you observe?

Set `log_checkpoints` to `on`, then the log file will show the cause of the checkpoint in the `checkpoint starting` message.

Are you sure that it is a good idea to avoid checkpoints? They are needed so that you can recover your database if there is a problem.

Comment: I think **Database Shutdown** triggered a checkpoint, in my case. I am aware of the fact that **is not a good idea to avoid checkpoints**, but what I need is to be able to execute `CHECKPOINT` **just manually**, and yes, I am aware that in case of something bad (for example: system crash) all updates are **lost**... Is this possible? (to have a "total control" of checkpoints)

Comment: It is not that updates are lost, but that recovery takes very long (fron the last checkpoint). Your `pg_xlog` directory will grow immensely. If you manually remove files from `pg_xlog`, you'll wreck your database. There is no way to avoid the checkpoints I have listed above.